# Retrive image from Firebase Storage in Swift TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-storage

Im struggling to retrieve image from Firebase Storage into my `TableView`. Appreciate any help. Below is my code:

tableviewcell code:

```
class HomeFeedCell : UITableViewCell {

    Var feeds = [HomeFeed]()
    var dbRef :FIRDatabaseReference!
    var storage : FIRStorage!


    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Location: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Type: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var FeedImage: UIImageView!

    func configureCellWith(product : HomeFeed)
    {
       Name.text? = product.name
        Location.text? = product.location
        Type.text? = product.type

       func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
          super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
       }

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My tableview:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeFeedCell

    let details = feeds[indexPath.row]

    cell.configureCellWith(details)

    return cell
}
```

I'm able to display the name, location, and type details successfully, but I'm just stuck on retrieving image. Below is my struct file:

```
struct HomeFeed {

    let key:String!
    let name:String!
    let location:String!
    let review:String!
    let type:String!
    let photoURL:String
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you'll want to do something like this:

Download in your table view cell (based on the name passed in to the cell, or some other unique identifier):

```
  // Create a storage reference from the URL
  let storageRef = storage.reference("name/of/my/object/to/download.jpg")
  // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
  storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
    // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
    let pic = UIImage(data: data)
    FeedImage.image = pic
  })
```

For more information, see [Zero to App: Develop with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), and it's [associated source code](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd), for a practical example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

***There are two ways you can get your image from url, Asynchronously and Synchronously, both i have explained below with usage***

**Synchronously:**

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.pathForResource("imageName", ofType: "jpg"), image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) 
{
  imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
  imageView.image = image
}
```

**Asynchronously:**

**Create a method with a completion handler to get the image data from your url**

```
func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: ((data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
    (data, response, error) in
    completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
 }.resume()
}
```

**Create a method to download the image (start the task)**

```
func downloadImage(url: URL){
print("Download Started")
getDataFromUrl(url: url) { (data, response, error)  in
    guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent ?? "")
        print("Download Finished")
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
 }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
print("Begin of code")
if let checkedUrl = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png") {
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    downloadImage(url: checkedUrl)
}
print("End of code. The image will continue downloading in the background and it will be loaded when finished.")
}
```

Hope this will help you!